# Are there any good Phonegap tutorials except for "Hello" stuff?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I want to start looking into Phonegap for deploying iOS and Android apps. I was wondering if there are any good Phonegap tutorials except for the basic "Hello" stuff.

Comment: I recommend this blog..
this contains a lot of tutorial links about creating phonegap applications.
http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/phonegapcordova-crib-sheet/

Answer (score 15):

I found the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/) to be pretty helpful (and I'm usually not a documentation kind of learner). They're not so much full apps, but show how you can target specific aspects of the device (camera, GPS, etc).

Also - not sure if you're looking for something like this, but I found Jonathan Stark's [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/) immensely helpful. It's not heavy on PhoneGap, but focuses more on using jQuery/jQTouch to develop your app (with PhoneGap being the final method for deployment). More of a step-by-step walkthrough of an app, start to finish.

Keep in mind PhoneGap just basically gives you hooks into your device. If you're talking about learning how to build for iPhone/Droid using HTML/CSS... Stark's (oneline, free) book is a good resource. It was for me, anyhow...

Comment: No prob. If either my response or Matt's fit what you were looking for... feel free to check it as your accepted answer. Upvoting works as well (though I think you need your reputation to be at 15 before you can do so).

These actions help "recognize" others, and increases the respondents' reputation. And, in turn, this sort of feedback provides incentive for others to contribute solutions/answers. Though looking at Matt's reputation... I think he's got me beaten by a coupla points.

Comment: Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is Nice tutortial

Comment: @avoision, Is this the correct url of "Stark's (oneline, free) book": http://ebookbrowsee.net/multi-platform-development-with-phonegap-notes-pdf-d438890038?

Comment: Chandra, that does not look correct. Try the author's site, here: http://jonathanstark.com/iphone-book

Answer (score 9):

There are [a ton of tutorials](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials) as well as [code snippets](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501516/Code-Snippets) and [Getting Started guides](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/21138550/Getting-Started) on the [PhoneGap Wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494772/FrontPage).

Comment: There are lots of tutorials, but none that seem to go far beyond showing how to setup a project in a given environment, which seems to be what Brad is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This example is very heavy, but there is good information in it, such as submitting a form and displaying things with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. After hours of searching, this tutorial has my solutions.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty exhaustive (exhausting?) [tutorial on our site](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aA_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap) showing you how to integrate Sencha Touch with PhoneGap, but it should generalize to any web app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go a bit more native on iOS development I suggest you to check out a tutorial I did about `NativeControls` on my site: [How To Setup And Use NativeControls In PhoneGap](http://www.dreamintech.net/2011/11/how-to-setup-and-use-nativecontrols-in-phonegap/)